# How to assign an int variable with a one-to-many phone number in SQL

Tags: java, sql

I want to assign an int variable with a phone number as one for many of the SQL table

```
   public void addData(long id, String menu_name, int quantity, double 
    total_price){
    // this is main holder key-value pair, used by SQLite functions for Android
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ID, id);
    values.put(MENU_NAME, menu_name);
    values.put(QUANTITY, quantity);
    values.put(TOTAL_PRICE, total_price);

    // try to insert new data to database using database object
    try{db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 3 tables.

1. Tables with primary key for id, int value, etc.
2. Tables with primary key for id, phone number, etc.
3. Tables with 2 columns. First is foreign key for primary key in table1 (with int value) and second is foreign key for primary key in table2 (with phone number)

After this steps you can create select for example: 
`SELECT p.number AS phone_number FROM custom_table_name ctn JOIN phones p ON ctn.id_phone = p.id WHERE ctn.id_int = 1`